# Composite cost function using angular distance between vectors and distance between points

Tags: optimization, vectors, mahalanobis-distance

I am trying to come up with a way to find the transformation parameters between two sets of planes and would like to get a cost function `C` which incorporates two functions `C1` and `C2` where

```
C1 = dot(n1,n2)
C2 = dist(p1,p2)
```

`n1` and `n2` are normal vectors and `p1` and `p2` are means of planes. However, I am not sure if

```
C = C1 + C2
```

can be used as a cost function to minimize the angle and distance together? If not, do I need to maximize them separately?

Comment: You can use whatever cost function you want to use. Just set up your mind and you will do.

Comment: Jokes aside, we can do few for help if nothing about the problem we know.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have added the explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two planes must be fitted to be equal, for a given unitary normal and distance from the origin:
$$
n_i\cdot (x - n_i\rho_i)=0
$$

with $n_1 \cdot n_2 \in [-1 \ 1]$, and $\rho \in$ , lets say, $[0 \ \rho_0]$.

Please confirm the previous boundary.

If so, the cost function would be:
$$
C(\mathcal P_1,\mathcal P_2)=\frac12n_1\cdot n_2 + \frac1{\rho_0}(\rho_1-\rho_2)^2
$$

In here both factors are equally penalized over the domain lengths.

Comment: I think the plane is given by n_i.(x_i-rho_i) = 0.

Comment: $\rho$ in here is the distance to the origin, unlike any arbitrary point, the closest point $n_i\rho$ is fixed, hence this equation is always unique.

Comment: Oh my mistake. Thanks for the solution.